# CSS3 calc with variables

Tags: html, firefox, css

I am calculating some widths and margins depending on the number of childs.

Is it possible in css3 to have a variable like:

```
.someClass {
   width: -moz-calc(nrOfChilds * 80px);
}
```

Some other classes I got are written as follows:

```
.anotherClass:nth-child(n) {
   margin-left: -moz-calc(n * 50px);
}
```

Is it possible to use some variables like n or nrOfChilds? At the moment I declare my second example several times and change the first manually?
I know javascript is a solution to this. But is there a native css3 solution for this?

/Kind regards

Christian

Comment: You could look at the CSS `flexible box model` to achieve dynamically flexible spacing based on your content. http://vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/flexbox/flexbox.html

Comment: [JQuery](https://jquery.com/) is easy to use, its a javascript plugin. Selector works like css and its simple to modify css ( [css and JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) )

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Nowadays all major browsers support calculated CSS values with custom variables, via:

- `calc(...)`

  - Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc
  - Browser support: https://caniuse.com/css-variables
- `var(--...)`

  - Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var
  - Browser support: https://caniuse.com/calc

### Example

```css
.somebar {
    /* I define the initial value of "--mydepth" */
    --mydepth: 1;
    width: calc(var(--mydepth) * 50px);
    
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}

.level1 {
    --mydepth: 2;
}
.level2 {
    --mydepth: 3;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example of: calc(var(--mydepth) * 50px)</h3>
<div class="somebar"></div>
<div class="somebar level1"></div>
<div class="somebar level2"></div>

<h3>Expected result (if supported by browser)</h3>
<div class="somebar" style="width:50px"></div>
<div class="somebar" style="width:100px"></div>
<div class="somebar" style="width:150px"></div>
```

Answer (score 10):

(As of 2012) There's no way to do this in CSS3.

As of 2019 (and earlier) see the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [.less](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) if using .NET server side.

Comment: I am considering it. But how will LESS know the number of childs I am declaring in my HTML?

Comment: How often does the number of children change? If seldom, could this be a LESS variable? If often, then this is probably a job for a javascript solution.

Answer (score 1):

there's no way to do this with only css3. You can use [.less](http://lesscss.org/) , that use dynamic behavior such as variables, mixins, operations and functions. Is based on JS. Or you can take the rails approach with the use of [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) . there's others, but I guess these two are the most popular for css extensions.

Comment: Thx some months ago I used sass and flexbox. No IE, but that doesnt matter.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in CSS3, neither using LESS or SASS. The only way is through javascript which should be quite simple to do.

Answer (score -2):

Example using SASS:-

```
$nrOfChilds: 20;

.someClass {
   width: calc(#{$nrOfChilds} * 80px);
}
```